# How to loop through a set of ranges from an array inside a for loop using readtable?

Tags: arrays, excel, matlab, matlab-deployment

I have a for loop that is calculating values using parameters from a spreadsheet. I want the for loop to loop through different ranges but I am receiving an error and I am not sure how to fix it.

```
e_params_components = ["'G3:G5'","'D3:D5'","'F3:F5'","'E3:E5'"];
h_params_components = ["'G6:G8'","'D6:D8'","'F6:F8'","'E6:E8'"];
for i = 1 : length(Material_Names)
    params_e = table2array(readtable(databaseFilename,  'Range', e_params_components(1)));    % Read in width indep parameters for e- - hardcoded for GaAs
    params_h = table2array(readtable(databaseFilename,  'Range', h_params_components(1)));    % Read in width indep parameters for holes - hardcoded for GaAs
    alpha_ = ionCoeff(params_e(1), params_e(2), params_e(3), Efield);
    beta_ = ionCoeff(params_h(1), params_h(2), params_h(3), Efield);
    k_ = beta_./alpha_;                        % Ionization coefficient ratio
    k_values = k_values + k_(i);
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using readtable (line 198)
Unable to determine range. Range must be of the form 'A1' (cell), 'A:B' (column-select), '1:5' (row-select), 'A1:B5'
(rectangle-select), or a valid named range in the sheet.
```

I should be able to use the strings that are contained in e_params_copmponents to put into the read table function

Answer (score 0):

You have to many quotes.

For example:

"'G6:G8'" is the string 'G6:G8' you want it to be the string G6:G8